# Should I have a layer between my ViewModel and DomainModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, domain-model

I have my domain model (used to tie in with EF and used for mapping to the DB):

```
public class Category : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    //Code removed for brevity
}
```

I then have a shared controller to show a category menu using this in my view:

```
@Html.Action("GetCategoryMenu", "Shared")
```

The Controller

```
[OutputCache(Duration = int.MaxValue, VaryByParam = "none")]
public ActionResult GetCategoryMenu()
{
    var viewModel = new CategoryMenuViewModel
    {
        Categories = _categoryService.Get().Where(c => c.ParentCategory != null && c.ParentCategory.Id == WebsiteContext.CurrentWebsite.CategoryId)
    };

    return PartialView("_CategoryMenu", viewModel);
}
```

And the ViewModel:

```
public class CategoryMenuViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

The question I now have is that if I implemented something like `category.GetUrl()` for use in my view where would this go? Is the domain model the correct place for something like this?

`GetUrl()` would run some logic and return a Url based on some conditions. I see this being used from the view itself to embed into a hyperlink. It would be run per category essentially just getting a Url in case I wanted to change how I generate them later on.

Essentially, I am trying to achieve this in my partial view to render a category menu:

```
@foreach (Category category in Model.Categories)
{
    <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
        <a href="@category.GetUrl()"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> @category.Name</a>
    </li>
}
```

I'm just looking for best practice advice at the moment as I want to make sure I understand the MVC pattern correctly because I have an odd feeling about putting a `GetUrl()` method against my domain model but I don't know why.

Comment: What is GetUrl and what does it do?  Is it rendered for each category in the View?

Comment: I've edited my post (towards the bottom) with that information. If I haven't clarified, let me know and I'll try again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to create your application in such a way that you could replace tiers which are on top of each others without touching the underlying tier. A classic example for this is the [three-tier architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Three-tier_architecture). This means that your GUI only accesses the logic tier (business models) and your logic tier only accesses the database tier (Entity Framework). Due to the way Entity Framework is designed the last part is a bit fishy: EF already mixes the logic tier with the data tier as you put business logic into the entity classes themselves.

However, for the upper two tiers you should respect this separation. Methods which perform GUI tasks, such as `GetUrl` should not be part of the domain classes. It might e.g. be that in the future you need to change the GUI and your URLs now have a different layout. Then you need to make a change to the domain model which is not how it should be.

The proper way would be to create an additional view model and then map the required properties from your business objects to the view model. However, you really want to avoid this you might think about defining extension methods for your business classes in your GUI project.

On a side note: I have done exactly what you are suggesting, i.e. use business objects obtained via Entity Framework as view models. Be aware of the limitations this brings, especially in regards to saving changes back to EF. You will usually still need to map the objects which are posted to you even if they are entities because they are instantiated by the MVC model binders and are not retrieved via the EF context, i.e. they can not be saved as updated versions of your existing objects. One way around this might be to create a custom model binder, but I do think you would be better off by creating view models and mappings instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just to clarify, I **do** have separate View Models and I don't use my business object as view Models (I think there are terminology issues here :) ). With that in mind, I assume you suggest having the logic to retrieve the Url in the view model to satisfy SOC and feed anything required to to generate that Url into the view model via the controller?

Comment: @webnoob Well, you are using your business objects as parts of your view model (`Category` objects in `CategoryMenuViewModel`) so you are passing business objects to your view and then using them there. This is what I meant. Yes, I suggest having the URL logic in the view model or maybe the controller, depending on what kind of information is required.

Comment: Right, I see what you mean now. SO, I need a view model for the actual view then another view model to represent the business model data itself. That makes a lot more sense and gives the `GetUrl()` method a home. Sounds like a plan. Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

> The question I now have is that if I implemented something like category.GetUrl() for use in my view where would this go? Is the domain model the correct place for something like this?

No! What if tomorrow your company decides to write an IPad app? Your domain model is still valid--the business logic and rights checking and all of that still applies--but you no longer use URLs. Clearly URL-generation logic does not belong here.

In ASP.NET MVC, the responsibility for generating URLs usually lies with methods on the UrlHelper class. Typically it's easy enough to use these methods directly:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Category", new{category.Id})"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> @category.Name</a>
```

But if you need to get code reuse out of this, I'd suggest you do it in the form of an extension method on the UrlHelper:

```
<a href="@Url.Category(category)"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> @category.Name</a>
```